# PDFjam convert a 2 page pdf into a one page pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfjam

I have a pdf that has 2 pages side by side on each page like so:

```
 ------------------
|        |         |
|        |         |
|        |         |
 ------------------
```

I want to convert this into 1 page per page like so:

```
 --------
|        |
|        |
|        |
 --------
```

So if the initial pdf is 10 pages, the final one would be 20 pages, and I need to preserve the order of the pages. How can I do this using pdfjam?

Comment: Found the answer here using a different tool.
https://superuser.com/a/1303929